# Expressions of action and energy momentum tensor in bc conformal field with central charge equals one

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I have a question with conformal field theory in Polchinski's string theory vol 1 p. 51.

For $bc$ conformal field theory 
$$ S=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int d^2 z b \bar{\partial} c  $$
$$ T(z)= :(\partial b) c: - \lambda \partial (: bc:) $$
with central charge $c=-3 (2 \lambda-1)^2 +1 =1$. Introducing $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ to replace the anticommuting fields $b$ and $c$ as following
$$b \rightarrow \psi =2^{-1/2} (\psi_1 + i \psi_2 )$$ and $$ c \rightarrow \bar{\psi} =2^{-1/2} (\psi_1 - i \psi_2)$$
It is claimed that
$$S=\frac{1}{4\pi} \int d^2 z \psi_1 \bar{\partial} \psi_1 + \psi_2\bar{\partial} \psi_2 (2.5.18b)$$
$$ T=- \frac{1}{2} \psi_1 \partial \psi_1 -\frac{1}{2} \psi_2 \partial \psi_2 (2.5.18c)$$

I cannot obtain the above expressions of $S$ and $T$. Here is my derivations. First I try to recover the anti-commuting characters of fields $b$ and $c$ by $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$.
For $$bc+cb=0$$ I have $$\psi_1 \psi_1 + \psi_2 \psi_2 =0$$
Then for the action
$$S=\frac{1}{4\pi} \int d^2 z \left( \psi_1 \bar{\partial} \psi_1 + i \psi_2 \bar{\partial} \psi_1 -i \psi_1 \bar{\partial} \psi_2 + \psi_2 \bar{\partial} \psi_2  \right)$$
(1) [Solved] Why the term $i \psi_2 \bar{\partial} \psi_1 -i \psi_1 \bar{\partial} \psi_2$ does not contribute to the action?

(2) How to derive (2.5.18c)?

Comment: You know, it's completely fine for you to ask multiple questions about Polchinski in the course of your studying; there's really no need to start every question with a disclaimer like "another stupid question from..." :)

Comment: For (1), you could try integration by parts and anti-commutativity of the fermions.

Comment: If $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ anti commutes, then I can let $i \psi_2 \bar{\partial} \psi_1 -i \psi_1 \bar{\partial} \psi_2$  disappears. But from $\{b,c\}=0$ I only get $\psi_1 \psi_1 + \psi_2 \psi_2=0$.

Comment: What do you get from $\{b, b\} = \{c , c\} = 0$?

Comment: That will give $\{ \psi_1,\psi_2 \}=0$... Are we sure $b$ and $c$ themselves anticommutes (perhaps yes, since it makes sense)? I thought only $\{b,c\}$=0

Comment: They do anticommute.

Comment: Sorry but $\{b,c\}$ is not equal to zero. In the same way, $\psi_1$ doesn't commute with itself, and similarly for $\psi_2$.

Comment: @Luboš Motl excuse me, why?

Comment: Because $b$ is the canonical momentum for $c$ - the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to $\partial_0 c$ - in the same way as $p$ is the momentum for $x$ in mechanics. The canonical quantization says that $[p,x]$ is nonzero much like $\{b,c\}$. It's similar for real fermions $\psi$ except that $\psi$ plays the role of its own momentum.